# Could not find compiled resource bundle 'components' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: ant, flex4

I'm building my Flex 4.6 project using ant. The Ant script also compiles a css file to swf, but when I run the application, it gives an error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'components' for locale 'en_US'.
Here is the piece of my ant script that builds the style file:

```
<mxmlc
  incremental="true"
  fork="true" 
  optimize="true"
  debug="false" 
  file="${app.dir}/src/main/resources/stylepacks/${stylepack}/styles.css"
  output="${output.dir}/stylepacks/${stylepack}/styles.swf">
    <source-path path-element="${app.dir}/src/main/flex" />
</mxmlc>
```

I've tried many possible solutions that I found, such as including the resource bundles:

```
<include-resource-bundles>components</include-resource-bundles>
```

or

```
<include-resource-bundles bundle="components" />
```

and referncing the Flex resource bundles:

```
<source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/framework/locale/en_US" />
```

but it all doesn't seem to work.
The application and the stylesheet uses both HALO and Spark elements, so I've tried with both themes, but then the build fails:

```
<compiler.theme file="${theme}" />
```

Does anyone have any more suggestions??

Comment: If you solved this, could you post your answer?

Comment: We couldn't find the problem, so we decided to rewrite the entire thing and it miraculously worked :$
All I can say is "Argh!"
Sorry I can't be of any real help.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to work through it as well.  My error was due to a typo in my <source-path> element :$

Comment: I have this issue now, been on this all day.